# Left align form labels and space out input elements

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to left align the labels on my form and space out the input and button element/s. Can anyone offer any advice on how I can get it done, while keeping the input elements centred?

**CSS code:**

```
.bt input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bt button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}

.bt button:hover {
    background-color: #818181;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.fbc {
    text-align: center;
}

.bt .fb {
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #585858;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
 <div class="bt fbc">
            <div class="fb">
            <label>Name (Required)
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required autofocus> 
            </label>
            <label>Email (Required)
            <input type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" required autofocus> 
            </label>
            <button>SUBMIT BOOKING</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r11qv9kh/1/

Comment: Adding text-align: left; to the .bt .fb class in your css will align the labels to the left of your form.

Comment: @MatthewJames Woops strike that last comment, I was mistaken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define new styles for labels:

```
.bt label {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 10%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

and change width styles for inputs:

```
.bt input {
    ...
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And in this case you don't have to modify HTML.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r11qv9kh/3/light/

Answer (score 1):

Your labels are inline elements, and therefore will get their text alignment from their parent element. You can give them a block display and assign their text alignment directly to get them going left.

HTML:

```
<label for="name">Name (Required)</label>
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>
```

CSS:

```
.bt label {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r11qv9kh/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will align your labels to the left:

```
Text-align: left;
```